# devexpres grid withedit functionality not invoking row updating event

Tags: devexpress, aspxgridview

i am using devexpress grid with edit functioality to update the records in the gridview
the codeis being done in asp.net & c#.net

but while clikcing the update after editing the records . it just shoes the progressbar runnning and doesn't invokes the updating event ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be an error on the serverside and the clientside is not updated since it's using a callback. Take a look at this screencast which can help you display the error:

http://community.devexpress.com/blogs/aspnet/archive/2008/07/23/video-how-to-handle-an-asp-net-ajax-callback-error.aspx